# Multiple layouts in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a project where each page needs to import an extra css or JS file **for only that page**. Is it a good practise to use a different layout file for each view? (I don't want my view files to contain references to css/JS files).

I mean i can have a different layout for each view but i don't know if it is the optimal way to do it.

Comment: *"I don't want my view files to contain references to css/JS files"* Why not? You could use [`content_for :head`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#understanding-yield) and place the CSS/JavaScript tag in the HTML `<head>` if not for that restriction.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Ideally, you need to provide some code for us to help you. Show us what you've tried already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Best strategy:

Don't worry about it and just let your app handle this for you. Minified CSS and JS file delivery isn't really that slow/big and Rails will compile your assets into single files in production.

---

If you're determined, it is possible (your mileage may vary depending on your Rails version, and usage of Sprockets or Webpacker)

And you'll really want to understand the [Rails asset pipeline](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) (for your version of Rails) before you go nerfing these settings.

### CSS inclusion/exclusion

You can ignore the asset pipeline and manually choose which CSS files to include, but you'll need to be diligent about doing this everywhere.

In your `app/views/layouts/application.html` file, you have a line like this inside the `<head>` tag:

`<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all' ... %>`

This is loading `application.css`, which is a compiled version of `app/assets/stylesheets/application.css` and will include all CSS from all other files inside `app/assets/stylesheets`

Depending on your version of Rails, you'll need to turn off asset pre-compilation in either `config/initializers/production.rb` or `config/initializers/assets.rb`:

`Rails.application.config.assets.precompile = []`

##### Warning: this will turn off ALL asset compilation, including JS. Be sure you have a strategy to re-include JS files (based upon your asset pipeline)

You will now need to implement some logic to handle what CSS is included when. This could be in `app/helpers/application_helper.rb`. It could use the view helper [`controller_name`], (https://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Metal/controller_name/class), for example, to determine which page you are on and fetch the correct CSS file.

Really rough example:

```
# app/helpers/application_helper.rb

module ApplicationHelper
  def css_file_chooser
     "/app/assets/stylesheets/#{controller_name}.css"
  end
end
```

Then in your `application.html` file, you can do something like this:

```html
<head>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag css_file_chooser, media: 'all' ... %>
 ...
</head>
```

The catch here is you'd need to have your specific CSS files named according to your controllers. E.g. if `controller_name` returns 'posts', you'd need to have a file: 'app/assets/stylesheets/posts.css'

If you do have some site-wide CSS that needs to be applied, you'd need to include a second `stylesheet_link_tag`:

In this case, if you put all your global styles into `app/assets/stylesheets/global.css`:

```html
<head>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'global', media: 'all' ... %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag css_file_chooser, media: 'all' ... %>
 ...
</head>
```

---

### JS inclusion/exclusion

It's a bit dusty, but [this article](https://brandonhilkert.com/blog/organizing-javascript-in-rails-application-with-turbolinks/) outlines a strategy that only loads a JS function or file if the `<body>` has certain `class` tags. I used to use it on my Rails 4 and 5 projects.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I used your last suggestion (JS inclusion/exclusion) and i think it was what i was looking for.